# Middleware para manipulação de post

Tags: laravel

Criei um middleware para verificar se a pessoa que deseja manipular um *post* é dona deste ou se é o super *admin*. Veja:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = \Auth::user();
    $postId = $request->route('post');
    $post = $user->posts->where('id', $postId)->first();

    if ($user->id == 2 || @$post->user_id == $user->id) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect()->route('post.index')
            ->with(['status' => 'danger', 'mensagem' => 'Este post não te pertence!']);
}
```

Mas neste trecho:

```
if ($user->id == 2 || @$post->user_id == $user->id) {
```

Tive que inserir um @ para suprimir um erro que ocorre quando o post não a ser manipulado não está relacionado ao usuário da sessão. Tem alguma forma mais adequada de fazer essa mesma lógica mas sem inserir mais um *if*?

Comment: Se estiver fazendo uso do L5.3 você esta procurando isso: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variável `$post` precisa ser checado se ele é diferente de `null`, então, tente esse ajuste:

```
if ($user->id == 2 || ($post && $post->user_id == $user->id)) {
```

ou

```
if ($user->id == 2 || (!is_null($post) && $post->user_id == $user->id)) {
```

<sub>**Observação:** não use `@` para suprimir um problema que tem como ser resolvido</sub>